Сохранение сообщений в телеграмм бот
Подскажите пожалуйста. Телеграмм бот с возможность подключения оператора. Есть возможность выполнять действия нажимая кнопки из меню.
1 пересланное сообщение просто в бот без активности общения с оператором кто-то видит, сохраняется?
2 телеграмм боты как-то привязывают id пользователя с номером телефона, если сообщал оператору автоматически?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.


пересылка сообщения = сообщение с вложением пересыламего 2) id пользователя конечно бот получает, и будет странно его не сохранить, ибо иначе как юзера идентифицировать. по поводу телефона - бот эта программа, если обучен искать в сообщениях номера телефонов и сохранять, то будет это делать, если нет, то нет.


Уточняю. Операторы с которыми можно пообщаться в опции бота видят отправленное сообщение, не команду или только переписку после переключения по команде? Или просто сообщение остаётся в архиве бота? Привязка id=номер могут сделать операторы в ручную после того как сообщил как базу или автоматически? (Номер скрыт в тлеграмм)
